# Jquery Chosen automatic select

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

I am using the Harvest Chosen jQuery plugin like so:

```
 $(".chzn_b").chosen();
```

It allows me to select multiple options from my select but sometimes when i land on the page i want to have some stuff preselected.
 How do i do that ?

Comment: Are you using it with a `<select>` element?

Comment: Yes, it's called on a select element and the select element has the options organised in optgroups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define the selected attribute on the option tag inside that select http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_selected.asp

Then Chosen should set that as the selected value.